# How to overwrite/delete saved images in app

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I am developing an app where user can save 13 screenshots and display them on a single view as thumbnails or as a full screen image. This is how I save the screenshots:

```
let fileName:String = self.stickerUsed + "saved" + ".png"
                    var arrayPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0] as! NSString
                    var pngFileName = arrayPaths.stringByAppendingPathComponent(fileName)

                    UIImagePNGRepresentation(resizeImage(screenshot!, newSize: CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.width, self.view.frame.height))).writeToFile(pngFileName, atomically:true)
                    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(pngFileName, forKey: self.stickerUsed)
                    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
```

and this is how i retrieve them:

```
 var defaultName:String = self.stickerUsed + "saved" + ".png"
                let path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(
                    .DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0] as! NSString
                let fileName = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
                    .stringForKey(stickerUsed) ?? defaultName
                let imagePath = path.stringByAppendingPathComponent(fileName)
                let image = UIImage(named: imagePath )
```

How do i overwrite the saved images ? When i use the code to save imageof a different screenshot with same filename and then retrieve it i get the previous image that was initially saved and new image is not overwritten!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made your code cleaner and fixed the problem! Comments will help you learn some basic stuff about how it works.

First, define function that gives you full filepath from filename:

```
func documentsPathWithFileName(fileName : String) -> String {

    // Get file path to document directory root
    let documentsDirectoryPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.CachesDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0] as! String
    return documentsDirectoryPath.stringByAppendingPathComponent(fileName)
}
```

And then, function that takes UIImage and saves it, or replaces it, depending:

```
func saveOverrideImage(screenshot : UIImage, stickerName : String) {

    // Get file path poining to documents directory
    let filePath = documentsPathWithFileName(stickerName)

    // We could try if there is file in this path (.fileExistsAtPath())
    // BUT we can also just call delete function, because it checks by itself
    NSFileManager.defaultManager().removeItemAtPath(filePath, error: nil)

    // Resize image as you want
    let image : NSData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(resizeImage(screenshot!, newSize: CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.width, self.view.frame.height)))

    // Write new image
    image.writeToFile(filePath, atomically: true)

    // Save your stuff to
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(stickerName, forKey: self.stickerUsed)
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
}
```

Also, following the same style, you can get image:

```
func imageForStickerName(stickerName : String) -> UIImage? {

    // Get file path poining to documents directory
    let filePath = documentsPathWithFileName(stickerName)

    // Get image from file on given local url
    return UIImage(contentsOfFile: filePath)
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks Jiri! I changed
`let documentsDirectoryPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.CachesDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0] as! String`
to
`let documentsDirectoryPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0] as! String`
and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try You can use

```
var error:NSError?
    var resultingURL:NSURL?
    let oldURL:NSURL = NSURL.fileURLWithPath("<old path>")!
    let newURL:NSURL = NSURL.fileURLWithPath("<new path>")!
    fileManager.replaceItemAtURL(oldURL,
        withItemAtURL: newURL,
        backupItemName: nil,
        options: .UsingNewMetadataOnly,
        resultingItemURL: &resultingURL,
        error: &error)
```

or you can delete old file and write new on, for more details on FileManager visit [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSFileManager/replaceItemAtURL:withItemAtURL:backupItemName:options:resultingItemURL:error:)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you incorporate this with my code written! I am new to swift and I am having trouble with the parameters and all!

Comment: It gives an error "cannot find member using UsingNewMetadataOnly"